# i want to select data from table according to date in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is that.
there is data in table with different dates in created column where i manually enter date in format `yyyy/mm/dd` with help of insert data 
i want to fetch data according to date in array.

and most important the date should be displayed only once and data similar to that date should be displayed in following array

for example 
data of 2017/07/04 should be displayed on in one array
data of 2017/07/03 should be displayed in one array

```
{date:2017/07/04}{{id=4,name=abc,created=2017/07/04},{id=5,name=def,created=2017/07/04}}
```

Comment: I don't keep the link to "how to ask a question" on hand ready to copy and paste. But we'd appreciate it if you could be a little more specific. What queries are you using? What does your MVC look like? This seems to be a JSON encode, what does that code look like?

Comment: Mundya foreach la de ik and array vich date key de against store kar la

Comment: Jaspreet singh what I can understand is that you want to select your data from database and then encode it to JSON data, but want to keep the date as parent key of your  `json-array`  is that so ?

Comment: Please put up your query or table structure so we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is *very* limited - I think you're after something like this:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($result->result_array() as $row){
    $array[$row['DATE']][] = array('id'=>$row['ID'],'name'=>$row['NAME'],'created'=>$row['DATE']);
}
```

Obviously you need to replace the capitalised field names with your DB references.

Should you then want it JSON encoded use `json_encode($array);`